# Streaming m4a with aiohttp

Tags: python, stream, aiohttp, m4a, pafy

Js audio players and m4a problem

Hello! I'm trying to stream m4a files with python aiohttp and play it in browser with some html5 players, like audio.js, Plyr. My problem is that it starts to play only when browser gets whole file. No problem with webm audio, only m4a. Is there a right way to do it?

```
async def stream2(request):
  fp = 'm.m4a'
  f = open(fp, 'rb')
  size = os.path.getsize(fp)
  res = web.StreamResponse(headers={'Content-type': 'audio/m4a', 'CONTENT-LENGTH': str(size)})
  await res.prepare(request)

  while True:
    datt = f.read(1024*32)
    if not datt: break
    await res.write(datt)

  return res
```

Js code:

```
var pl=$('<audio>').attr('src', '/audio.m4a?vid='+data.id);
pl.attr('id', 'player');
pl.attr('data-plyr-config', '{"autoplay": true}');
pl.attr('preload', 'auto');
var cont=$('#playercontainer');
cont.empty();
cont.append(pl)
```

Answer (score -2):

Problem solved. I write my custom http 206 partial content

Comment: Please provide the code of the controller to have a better idea how this is solved.